# How to make apache access log show the value of the host header

Tags: apache, logging

Let's say my site is accessible as http://www.example.com and http://www.example.net. I'd like to know which of the two addresses people are using to connect to my site. How can I configure apache logging to show this for every request?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the documentation you can use the `LogFormat` directive to replace the default setting for the format that is logged into the access file.

The default is: `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b"`

Adding the `%{Host}i` placeholder in there should add the hostname specified in the received request: `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t %{Host}i \"%r\" %>s %b"` You obviously can make further modifications to your liking.

Doing that I succeeded to generate this log entry ("vidar.site" is the host name typed inside my browser for a test request):

```
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Feb/2016:18:44:53 +0100] vidar.site "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 580
```

Typically that command is used several times within your http server configuration to define a number of "nick names" for commonly used log formats. I suggest you add an additional such nick name (an additional `LogFormat` directive) and use that in the specific log configuration of your virtual hosts.

I suggest you take a look at the documentation yourself, since that *always* should be your primary source of information:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat

Comment: Thank you, arkascha. Looks like LogFormat directive goes into httpd.conf, which I don't have access to in shared hosting. I do have acces sto .htaccess. any way to do this with .htaccess?

Comment: No, sorry. You cannot modify the basic function of a service without access to its configuration.

Comment: Thanks. At least I can stop searching now.